# Objective-C inheritance, string propagation to superclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, nsstring

First of all, I'm a beginner in objective-C.
At the moment I'm trying to resolve the following problem:

```
@interface Animal : NSObject {
  @private
  NSString* m_name;
}
-(Animal*) initName:(NSString*)name;
-(void) printName;

@implementation Animal
-(Animal*) initName:(NSString*)name {
  self = [super init];
  m_name = name;
  return self;
}
-(void) printName {
  NSLog(@"%s", m_name);
}
@end

@interface Bird : Animal {
}
-(Bird*) initName:(NSString*)name;

@implementation Bird
-(Bird*) initName:(NSString*)name {
  self = [super initName:name];
  return self;
}
@end

int main() {
  Animal* bird = [[Bird alloc] initName:@"abird"];  // warning: assignment from distinct Objective-C type
  [bird printName];  // prints invalid letters
  [bird release];
}
```

I want to propagate the constructor argument `name` to the superclass, but it doesn't work.
I also tried to print the name inside the constructor without any success.

All necessary headers are included. The warning `warning: assignment from distinct Objective-C type [enabled by default]` when creating the child class object is the only warning I get.

Does anyone has an idea how I could solve this problem?

Greetings Dan

Comment: What compiler do you use? The only warning I get (using Xcode 4.6.3) is *"format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'NSString *'"* in the line `NSLog(@"%s", m_name);` ...

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that's weird. Assigning an expression of type pointer-to-subclass to a variable of type pointer-to-superclass must be OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m_name` is an `NSString`, not a `char *`. You have to log it using the `%@` format specifier instead of `%s`. Read the documentation for format strings.

Comments:

- Objective-C is not C++. Don't try to enforce C++ style naming conventions. Call that instance variable `name`, or `animalName`, or `theName` or whatever. Don't call it `m_name`.
- The initializers are conventionally called `initWithWhatever:`, not `initWhatever:`. It reflects better the purpose of the method (you init the object with the name, and not the name itself).
- **Do check the return value of** `[super init]`. If it returns `nil`, your initializer will crash. An idiomatic solution is `if (self = [super initWithName:name])`
- The initializer methods, again conventionally, return `id`.

Comment: nice comments, appreciate it.

Comment: @user0000001 You're welcome. If you'd like to learn more about good Objective-C style and Cocoa conventions in general, I suggest you read [Apple's official coding guidelines.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer...
First of all thanks for your hints, they were really quite useful!

And you're right. I had to print out with the correct format specifier. That solved it! Thanks!